# How to use urllib in python 3 ? 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3

I am using anaconda and python 3 - i wrote below but not working for some reason. I am very new to python please help ! thank you.

```
import urllib.request 

x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com')

print(x.read())
```

Comment: Can you tell us what _exactly_ is wrong? Otherwise, you probably wont't get a useful solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `ssl.SSLContext()` and assuming you have proper CA certs installed, you can either create one directly or use `ssl.create_default_context(...)`, e.g.:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> resp = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com', context=ssl.SSLContext())
>>> resp.status
200
```

Alternatively, use a higher level library like [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)